# show site in my app

Tags: android

good day,
I'm new here
I use this code for an RSS reader.
when this activity starts then it will open a browser.
but I want this shown in my app by webview can anyone help me how to do this.

Thanks for the answers.
I already have a listview containing the links from the rss feed.
I will try tomorrow

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) links.get(position));
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a webview in your layout.  Then call

webview.loadUrl(url);

That will load the url in the webview.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to shown website in my app by webview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

package com.tgmcians.android;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

And add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```